# What does armel stand for?

Tags: debian, arm

The ABI *armhf* stand for ARM Hard-Float but what is *el* an abbreviation for in *armel*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e` stands for [EABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface#EABI); the `l` for [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @August, just because it sounds good doesn't make it true (and Wikipedia is wrong here). I've dug up a video of the actual talk in which the `armel` architecture was presented, and `armel` is explicitly equated to little-endian ARM.

Answer (score 11):

`el` stands for little-endian; see the [email](https://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2006/04/msg00019.html) explaining (briefly) the decision; the follow-up emails contain more information. Endianness isn't the most distinguishing feature of `armel`, but that's the name that was chosen...

Further evidence is in Wookey's Debconf7 talk introducing the `armel` architecture; in the [video](https://chuangtzu.ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/debian-meetings/2007/debconf7/high/148_Debian_Armel_Port.ogg) at 26:47 he explicitly says "`armel`, basically little-endian ARM".

Other architectures using `el` in the same way include `mipsel` and `ppc64el`.

As pointed out by [Kurt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/231/kurt), `el` is the initials of "little-endian" read in little-endian order.

Comment: OK, but why "el" for Little-Endian and not "le"?

Comment: Heh its a typical computer science joke, when sending the bits in a byte in little-endian you start with the right-most one first. In big-endian its left-to-right.